# React native create rectangle bottom, plus half rectangle is cut by circle

Tags: reactjs, native, shapes

[image]Hello I am having task to create custom shape figure. On the bottom the shape of figure is rectangle and on half top of rectangle is cut by circle shape. Can anyone give me direction where to go from now?

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Icon} from 'react-native-elements'

class BottomNavigator extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'column',
                backgroundColor: '#f8f4f4'

            }}>
                <View style={{ position: 'absolute', alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: '#f8f4f4', width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 35, bottom: 25, zIndex: 10 }}>
                    <Icon
                        name='add'
                        type='material'
                        color='#f00'
                        containerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        reverse
                        size={28}
                        onPress={() => {}}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: '#2196F3', bottom: 0, zIndex: 1, width: '100%', height: 60, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 15, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
                    <Icon
                        name='menu'
                        type='material'
                        color='#fff'
                        onPress={() => {}}

                    />
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <Icon
                            name='favorite'
                            type='material'
                            color='#fff'
                            onPress={() => {}}
                            containerStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 16 }}
                        />
                        <Icon
                            name='search'
                            type='material'
                            color='#fff'
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default BottomNavigator;
```